# Recurrence Relations: general process for solving first order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So I had asked a question prior to this one about recurrence relations, but apparently it was a bad one to ask. So I'm trying again to understand how to solve these babies... Here it is:

$$
3a_{n+1}-4a_n=0, n>=0, a_1=5
$$

What is the general process for solving a relation like this?

Comment: It is identical to the one you just asked about.

Comment: The slightest web search would've turned up [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)...

Comment: The Wikipedia article isn't exactly clear for someone who is just learning it. I did read that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only have two terms, it just becomes a power law like the last one.  In this case you get $a_n=\left(\frac34\right)^na_0$

Probably you are looking for relations with three terms, like the Fibonacci one:
$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$  You might look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)